# How to implement several 'threads' running in only one thread

Tags: java, c, multithreading, scala, actor

Lately I've been thinking: How do they implement several 'threads' in only one thread?

I mean, how they implement several parallel running pieces of code in only one thread? How they save the state of the 'thread', create an interrupt and pass the CPU to the next one?

I think that the Scala-actors implement this. But how?

This can be answered for JVM or C, it doesn't matter. I just really want to learn the theory of it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) and [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) here.

Coroutines give up the control when they are ready to do it, without any interruption, so question about interruption is irrelevant here. Scala actors are implemented as coroutines.

Green threads are user-mode threads implemented by virtual machine without use of native OS capabilities. Obviously, virtual machine can insert any instructions into the code being executed in order to check whether it need to switch to another thread.

Answer (score 4):

With actors it's simple, instead of using one thread per actor you use the same thread for executing messages for multiple actors. However, if an actor performs a blocking call or a heavy computation, another thread must be used to execute messages in other actors.

Green threads are light weight threads that can be implemented at the VM level. Green threads are always mapped to one or more OS threads. Synchronization and thread switching is handled in user space by the VM, which can significantly reduce overhead. However, there are drawbacks to green threads, for example IO calls might cause the thread to block and then the VM can't "reuse" the OS thread for another green thread and must instead use an additional OS thread.

Another solution is to use continuations, as implemented in the Scala compiler. The interruption and resuming of execution is then handled at the JVM bytecode level where local state is saved and restored. No VM support is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like tasks in an ExecutorService or ScheduledExecutorService in Java?

These tasks are added to a queue and preformed to completion. When one finishes another one starts.  If you have a loop with a delay, you can use a repeating scheduled tasks instead.  It complete for each iteration and allows another tasks to run.

If you want to know more details you might find reading the code interesting.

Comment: @Jose Leal, do you mean like threads? When you have light weight tasks in a thread/thread pool and threads which can share a CPU already, what would threads inside a thread gain you?

Answer (score 2):

Use [coroutines](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2010/09/scala-coroutines.html)

Comment: I think the question is more about how you can implement preemptive multithreading of n threads on 1 kernel thread.

Answer (score 2):

The [Akka library](http://akka.io/) is a really nice implementation of the actors model. It's got a pretty good straight Java API (in addition to the Scala one), and [the doc is pretty good](http://akka.io/docs/akka-1.0/untyped-actors-java.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have the threading package in the user code register itself for some sort of timer interrupt from the kernel.  Whenever it receives such an interrupt, it can tell the kernel to halt execution of all of the kernel threads that are themselves running multiple different threads.  For each of those threads, the timer interrupt code can inspect the stack for those threads, record important information (registers, stack pointer, program counter, etc.) in an auxiliary location, then load in the stored information for another one of the simulated threads running on that actual thread.  It can then resume the kernel thread running the simulated thread.  In this way, you can simulate context switching between the multiple threads running on a single kernel thread.

To implement something like locking, you could keep track of all the lock information locally in your user space.  Whenever a simulated thread tries to acquire a lock, you can check whether the thread can successfully get the lock.  If so, you just give it the lock.  Otherwise, you simulate a context switch by swapping out what simulated thread is running on that real thread, then marking the simulated thread as blocked until the lock becomes free again.

This is just a start - there's a lot of other details here (what if one of the simulated threads tries to do a blocking I/O operation?  You can't just block the kernel thread, since that would halt all the simulated threads!), but this is the gist of the idea.